# Ansible install fails on RHEL 7

Tags: python, ansible, rhel7

```
yum install ansible
```

fails on RHEL 7 because of the following dependency error

```
Error: Package: python-jinja2-2.2.1-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python34-3.4.3-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               python(abi) = 3.4
Error: Package: python-jinja2-2.2.1-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have the latest python, but ansible dependency requires older version.
How do i resolve this issue. I am not able to build ansible from sources for the very same reason.

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: This is not really an programming question, it should be posted to servervault instead.

Comment: go it...will keep in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at this moment a dependence error, the best way to install ansible is by pip.

first install this:

```
# yum install python-dev python-pip
```

then install:

```
# pip install ansible
```

Yum is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

The **python-jinja2** package can be found in the *optional-rpms* repository. So if you are running RHEL7, you can do something like:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-desktop-optional-rpms
```

Or you can set `notify-only=0` in `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf`.

Then try `yum install ansible` again.